# select last n row from a table in mysql without using order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

```
select * from employee limit select count(*)-1 from employee,1;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(*)-1 from employee,1' at line 1

Comment: The value of `LIMIT` has to be a literal, you can't put an expression there. And if you want to use a `SELECT` query as an expression, it has to be inside parentheses.

Comment: ... and LIMIT without ORDER BY returns random records.

Comment: This is a problem that is solvable in multiple ways if you permit order. Why is order not permitted here? If you don't specify order, you don't have any guarantee of which records are selected, so why not just ignore the last record read in the application?

Comment: What is your definition of `last` then?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72178/last-row-from-a-query-without-order-by  check this link

Comment: The only way to use calculated LIMIT parameters - prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work

```
select * from your_table except 
select top ((select count(*) from your_table) - how many rows you want)* from your_table
```

Comment: Neither except nor top are available in mysql